# How to reuse a return sub-block within a function?

Tags: java

My Iterator has a next() function with several return statements. Each statement is preceded by a couple of assignment statements.

Now, normally I would have extracted that code to a shared function. However, the caveat is that part of that shared code is a return statement.

How do you suggest I repurpose that code?

Comment: Post a **real** example; this code is (as you noted) ***absurd***.

Comment: done, hope this helps.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? a only `return` statement? or want to `extract common functions`?

Comment: @yurmix I might be mistaken, but aren't you calling `targetTime = targetTime.plus(period);` in all branches? Then you can move this line before the several `if` statements (assuming there are no side effects in doing so). Please edit your question to include the full source code you have, maybe even a [mcve]. Using https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might also be a try since it is a question about refactoring your code.

Comment: @sagarr extract common functions

Comment: I think you should paste your code for better improvement.

Comment: I saw your original code that you pasted and I dont think there anything common code that you can extract.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it and I can actually create an inner function (either named or anonymous) with the same return type as the outer function, then call it and return its result.